# How to change background color of highlighted line during debug process in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, colors, editor

How do I change the background color of the selected frame in the debugger?

In this following image, I have selected `performCreate:7009` frame from the Debugger menu, but I don't like the almost invisible background color in the editor above. I am unable to find the correct property from `Preferences --> Editor --> Color Scheme` setting. Please Help!

[image]

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Debugger --> Execution point` ?? That's for editor area only; frames should be using GUI Theme colors.

Comment: That works well for the *current* execution point... but I am trying to change the color of the highlighted line on selecting one of the previous execution point from `Debugger | Frames` window. In my screenshot above, `onCreate(..)` is the current execution point, but I had selected `performCreate:7009` which is the previous frame

Comment: `Not top frame` style then?

Comment: It worked! Thanks

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks from me too.   Suggest you enter it as the Answer.  To review - the style is:  `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Debugger | Not top frame` - and I just slid the brightness slider up to 140 to make the highlight visible (instead of very hard to see).  Note:  A shortcut to find this setting is to simply search for `not top frame` in `Help | Find Action...`